# Converting ODP.NET core reader's result to dataset or list

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, odp.net

I'm working on a project where I need to connect to an oracle DB. I also want to code fast and want to avoid defining entities and using EntityFramework for persistency.

Based on oracle examples, to retrieve data from the DB, I need to rely on a reader that I can get using "cmd.ExecuteReader()" then use a while(reader.read()) to loop through results.

I found this is kind of annoying. So after making sure that I'm receiving data using the reader way, I've tried what seemed to me to be a way to convert the whole result to a list of object, but this triggered and infinite loop.

Here's what I've tried :

```
var result = new List<object>();
        try
        {
            _connection = new OracleConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
            _connection.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = _connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from <table>";

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                result = reader.OfType<object>().ToList();  
               
            }
         
        }
        finally
        {
           if(_connection != null) _connection.Close();
          
        }

        return result;
    }
```

What is the best way to use ODP.NET Core to get results as a list, a dataset or maybe in JSon format ?

UPDATE :

using OracleDataAdapter also triggers an endless loop :

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            _connection = new OracleConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
            _connection.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = _connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from <table>";
            OracleDataAdapter ora = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            ora.Fill(data);
        }
        finally
        {
           if(_connection != null) _connection.Close();
          
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: You can use the Oracle Data Adapter :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter?view=netframework-4.8&force_isolation=true  A reader only reads one row of a database  and reading into a list will not work.

Comment: Don't edit the question to include an answer. You only need to add the answer below (like you have done).

Answer (score 0):

using OracleDataAdapter works ! Endless loop is caused due to large data size. Here's the working code :

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        _connection = new OracleConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
        _connection.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = _connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from <table>";
        OracleDataAdapter ora = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        ora.Fill(data);
    }
    finally
    {
       if(_connection != null) _connection.Close();
      
    }
    return data;
}
```